# Ошибка в visual studio. с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

[мой код](https://pastebin.com/szBMaeZT):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    int** matrix;
    int size;
public:
    //3 конструктора

    //конструктор по умолчанию
    Matrix()
    {
        //cout << "конструктор по умолчанию" << endl;
        size = 2;
        matrix = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;


    }
    //конструктор с параметрами
    Matrix( int SIZE)
    {
        //cout << "конструктор с параметрами" << endl;
        size = SIZE;

        matrix = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j(0); j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
    //конструктор копирования
    Matrix(const Matrix &m)
    {
        //cout << "конструктор копирования " << endl;
        size = m.size;

        matrix = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for(int j = 0;j<size;j++)
            matrix[i] = m.matrix[i];

    }
    //МЕТОДЫ



    //сложение матриц
    void addition(Matrix &matr)
    {
        //cout << "сложение" << (int)this << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] += matr.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    //вычитание матриц
    void subtraction(Matrix &matr)
    {
        //cout << "вычитание" << (int)this << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] -= matr.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    //умножение матриц
    void multiplication(Matrix &matr)
    {
        //cout << "умножение" << (int)this << endl;
        int** matrix1 = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix1[i] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix1[i][j] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                {
                    matrix1[i][j] += (matrix[i][k] * matr.matrix[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[]matrix1[i];
        delete[]matrix1;
    }
    //норма матрицы
    void norma()
    {
        //cout << "норма" << (int)this << endl;
        int max = 0;
        int sum;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                sum += abs(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            if (sum > max)
                max = sum;
        }
        cout << endl << "norma: " << max << endl;
    }


    //перегрузка операторов

    //оператор сложения
     Matrix& operator+(Matrix &matrica)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] += matrica.matrix[i][j];
        }
        return *this;
    }
     //оператор вычитания
     Matrix& operator-(Matrix &matrica)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                 matrix[i][j] -= matrica.matrix[i][j];
         }
         return *this;
     }
     //оператор умножения
     Matrix& operator*(Matrix &matrica)
     {
         int** matrix1 = new int*[size];
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             matrix1[i] = new int[size];
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                 matrix1[i][j] = 0;
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
             {
                 for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                 {
                     matrix1[i][j] += (matrix[i][k] * matrica.matrix[k][j]);
                 }
             }
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
             {
                 matrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j];
             }
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             delete[]matrix1[i];
         delete[]matrix1;

         return *this;
     }
     //оператор присваивания
     Matrix& operator=(Matrix &matrica)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                 matrix[i][j] = matrica.matrix[i][j];
         }
         return *this;
     }


     //функция вывода на экран
    void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                cout  << matrix[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //деструктор
    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[]matrix[i];
        delete[]matrix;
    }
};
//возведение в квадрат
//void SQR(Matrix *Msqr, int count, int q)
//{
//
//  Msqr[q].show();
//  if(q<=count)
//  Msqr[q] = Msqr[q] * Msqr[q];
//  
//  Msqr[q].show();
//      
//  
//}

void SQR(Matrix *matrixSqr, int count, int q)
{

    matrixSqr[q].show();

    matrixSqr[q].multiplication(matrixSqr[q]);

    matrixSqr[q].show();

}

int main()
{
    system("color 0b");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(time(NULL));

    Matrix matrixSqr[5];
    //приравниваем все матрицы;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        matrixSqr[i] = matrixSqr[0];

    SQR(matrixSqr,5,3);

    Matrix K1, K2(5), K3(K1), m1(2), m2(2), m4(2), m5(2);


    cout << "m1: "<<endl;
    m1.show();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "m2: " << endl;
    m2.show();
    cout<<endl;
    //складываем
    cout << "m1+m2: "<<endl;
    m1 = m1 + m2;
    m1.show();
    cout << endl;
    //вычитаем
    cout << "m1-m2: "<<endl;
    m1 = m1 - m2;
    m1.show();
    cout << endl;
    //умножаем
    cout << "m1*m2: "<<endl;
    m1 = m1 * m2;
    m1.show();
    cout << endl;
    //присваиваем
    cout << "m2=m1: " << endl;
    m2 = m1;
    m2.show();
    cout << endl;



    cout << "m4: " << endl;
    m4.show();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "m5: " << endl;
    m5.show();
    cout << endl;
    m4.multiplication(m5);
    cout << "m4*m5: " << endl;
    m4.show();
    cout << endl;
    m4.norma();



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Все работает. Но после "нажмите любую клавишу чтобы продолжить" вылетает ошибка. Именно когда я в первом конструкторе ставлю size больше нуля. Если size = ноль, то все нормально, но тогда не не выводится матрица в квадрате. Может что-то с очисткой памяти не так. Спасибо.

[image: скриншот msgbox'а с ошибкой]

Comment: Heap corruption может иметь ряд причин. Две наиболее распространенные - buffer overrun - когда пишете в аллоцированную память больше, чем выделено места, и вторая - double free когда delete вызывается для уже один раз удаленного указателя. Сообщение, которое показано, это уже последствия ошибки произошедшей где-то ранее

Comment: У вас вообще странное решение - те же умножения и сложения по сути операции с присваиванием результата мамой исходной матрице. Зачем? По логике вы должны создавать новую матрицу и возвращать ее. Сейчас ваше `m1 = m1*m2;` выполняет умножение на месте, а потом по сути присваивает `m1` самой себе. Я уж молчу о не использованной нигде константности.

Comment: Кроме того, в операциях не проверяется их возможность - что размеры матриц это позволяют.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в конструкторе копирования `Matrix(const Matrix &m)`

Вместо:

`matrix[i] = m.matrix[i];`

Должно быть:

`matrix[i][j] = m.matrix[i][j];`

Иначе указатели в одной матрице переписываются указателями другой и из-за этого потом падает вызов деструктора.